# Set value for all rows in a datatable without for loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable, for-loop

I'm trying to set the same value for all rows for a single column in a datatable without using for loop. Can anyone suggest any faster methods to achieve the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not unless you count `foreach`. One way or another, you'll need to loop.

If you use the `DataTable` version, the fastest approach is to use the `DataColumn` accessor, i.e.

```
var col = table.Columns["Foo"];
foreach(var row in table.Rows)
    row[col] = value;
```

As an alternative : since this presumably relates to a database, write the TSQL manually to set all the values appropriately (i.e. with a *suitable* `where` clause in the TSQL).

```
update [theTable]
set [theColumn] = theValue
where --TODO - something sensible
```

Comment: The datatable is already populated with data but each time it enters a specific function, some of the columns get a value. When the datatable is again passed to the same fucntion again I want to set some specific values. Foreach works well and it is already working, but its very slow. My problem is with the slowness of Foreach construct.

Comment: @Soham `foreach` is actually very fast. If it is slow for you, then the fundamental problem is that you have loaded **too much data**. It is generally not necessary to load an entire table, for example. You might get an improvement by moving to a direct type model (rather than `DataTable`), but either way this is `O(n)` - it is simply the difference in the linear multiplier. The problem here is the size of the `n` - nothing to do with the `foreach`.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you mean by direct type model?

Comment: @soham Using specific classes (i.e. `public class Customer {...} public class Order {...}`) instead of using DataTable. DataTable is a *general purpose* tool - it has overheads as a result.

Comment: "One way or another, you'll need to loop. ". This isn't true, see my post below

Comment: @Julian: No, you're also using a loop, you just can't see it, it's hidden from the developer and sits in [`DataColumn.EvaluateExpression`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,d3b24c1951b112d9,references). It's called from the `Expression` setter.

Answer (score 21):

yes, this is possible, even without loop! This can be done with `Expression` property. Keep in mind that string values should be quoted, otherwise it sees this as another columnname.[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

This will set the column 'col1' with the string value `a`:

```
preview.Columns["col1"].Expression = "'a'";
```

This will display in 'col1' the value of the column 'col2':

```
preview.Columns["col1"].Expression = "col2";
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that even this approach uses a loop. It's just hidden from the developer and sits in [`DataColumn.EvaluateExpression`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,d3b24c1951b112d9,references). It's called from the `Expression` setter.

Comment: if ones wants to bind the datatable/dataview to MVVM to wpf etc, please notice that .Expression makes the column ReadOnly. Even if is not specified as ReadOnly in the xaml. I ended up using foreach() loop for that reason

Answer (score 8):

Have you considered removing and re-adding the column with a default value?

```
dt.Columns.Remove("FilterText")
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "FilterText",
                                      .DataType = GetType(String),
                                      .DefaultValue = "Jam and chips"})
```

*(assuming your column name is FilterText, and you want to set it to "Jam and chips")*

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this type of problem where the Select All Checkbox was used to set a column "sel" to 1 or 0, the foreach loop is very slow, I grabed the idea from @Jonathan answer which is more faster, but with some minor modification as the With clause do not work in c#

```
dtEmpList.Columns.Remove("sel");
dtEmpList.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sel",typeof(bool)(chkSelectAll.Checked ? "1" : "0")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//--Adding column datatype string in C#

string strDocument = "yourStringValue";

DataColumn col = new DataColumn();
col.ColumnName = "document";
col.AllowDBNull = false;
col.DataType = typeof(string);
col.DefaultValue = strDocument ;
dr.Columns.Add(col);
```