# How to change the DataTable Column Value without looping?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a DataTable which has 4 columns. I want to change the 3rd column's value as "0". 
Below is my DataTable.

```
ID             Name            Value      Type
----            ----            -----      -----
1              Sam              250        2
2              Rai              324        3
3              Tim              985        8
```

My Desired Result should be like below:

```
 ID             Name            Value     Type
----            ----            -----     ------
1              Sam              0          2
2              Rai              0          3
3              Tim              0          8
```

How to achieve this without looping? Any suggestions please.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063551/set-value-for-all-rows-in-a-datatable-without-for-loop

Comment: @Waqas: But there too they had used foreach...

Comment: OK, just one question - why not loop?

Comment: I have changed the Column's value using loops only. Suppose if the rows are more then it would take more time. thats why I specified without using loops.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about this? ↓ without loop....

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    table.Columns.Add("col1");
    table.Columns.Add("col2");

    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "1" });
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "1" });
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "1" });
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "1" });

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        Console.WriteLine(row["col2"].ToString());

    Console.WriteLine("***************************************");

    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("col2");
    dc.DataType = typeof(int);
    dc.DefaultValue = 0;

    table.Columns.Remove("col2");
    table.Columns.Add(dc);

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        Console.WriteLine(row["col2"].ToString());


    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a simple trick here. Delete row and re-add it to the table.

```
 dt.Columns.Remove("Value");
 dt.Columns.Add("Value", type(System.Int32), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DataRow[] rows = myDataTable.Select("id = 'myIdValue'); 
//If you don't want to select a specific id ignore the parameter for select.

for(int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i ++)
{
      rows[i]["value"] = 0;
}
```

[DataTable.Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5ce3dyt%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: thank u so much for your valuable contribution to my question.

Answer (score 1):

if you know the ID you can simply filter for it using Select or Find (not remember exactly but I think is Select), once you have the row, you can assign column values.

I am sure there is also a better LINQ oriented way but this old school ADO.NET/System.Data approach should work anyway.

Comment: But Select is only to filter the datatable by giving its column value. How can I set the value as "0" for all the column values?

Comment: thank u so much for your valuable contribution to my question.