# Bulk update column in Data Table based on another column

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable

I have a data table that contains dates in a format of yyyymmdd.  I would like to add a datetime column to the table that contains the date value of that column.

Now the problem is that the table contains a lot of records and looping through all the records takes some time.  Are there a way to do a bulk update or a use the Expression as from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063551/set-value-for-all-rows-in-a-datatable-without-for-loop) post?

Something like:

```
table.Columns.Add("MyDate", typeof(DateTime)).Expression = 
DateTime.ParseExact("'strDateField'", "yyyymmdd", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

(Statement above does not compile which is expected, but only posted as to provide an example of what I'm trying to achieve)

Comment: What is compilation error?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

Comment: Exactly it should give this error, as Expression expects String. Please refer my answer below for details.

Comment: I have corrected expression in my answere, please try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression use a limit set of SQL functions exposed by .net for operations on data table columns, refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx

You can try an arrangement like below

```
dt.Columns.Add("MyDate", GetType(Date)).Expression = "SUBSTRING(strDateField,5,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(strDateField,7,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(strDateField,1,4)";
```