# Performing Calculation ACCESS

Tags: database, ms-access, finance

I have a table loaded in Access (although the original file is a txt.file) with some loan characteristics and would like to create another table  containing the cash-flows  of these loans (“how much money are received every X month).
Here is a sample of my original table:

ID ---- LoanNbr ---- EntryDate ------ ClosingDate ----- Amount ---- Repayment ---- Frequency.

1 ----- 101 ---------- 1-1-2010 -------- 31-12-2012 ------ 1000E ------ 100E ------------ 1Month

2 ----- 102 ---------- 15-6-2012 ------- 31-12-2014 ------ 5000E ------ 250E ----------- 3Month.

....

And here is a sample of the output for loan 1:

ID ----- LoanNbr ----- EntryDate ----- Period --------- BeginLimite ----- Repayment ----- EndLimite.

1 ------    101 ----------- 1-1-2010 ------- 01-2010 ------ 1000 ------------- -100 --------------- 900

1 ------ 101 ----------- 1-1-2010 ------- 02-2010 --------  900 -------------   -100 --------------- 800

1 ------ 101 ----------- 1-1-2010 ------- 03-2010 --------  800 -------------   -100 --------------- 700

...

The calculations in themselves are not heavy at all, I just haven’t figured out how to perform them using a DBMS.
I am also opened to other suggestions concerning software/language that could be used with this set up.

Thanks in advance!
Jack

Answer (score 0):

There're a few major ways of doing that:

1. You can create a query a field of which will be calculated. 
   https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-14a60733-2580-48c2-b402-6de54fafbde3
2. You can extend the data by adding and extra column, create a VB script, which will run against the table data and insert the calculated value in a field.
   [Set value for all rows in a datatable without for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063551/set-value-for-all-rows-in-a-datatable-without-for-loop)
   I would go with a simples approach which is the 1st way of doing it.

But there're advantages and disadvantages to both.

Comment: I suggest a calendar table.